# Clickable Items in listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I m trying to make my listview items clickable; but cannot get it working properly. When I click on an item it shifts screen but not to the desired screen. Here is the code

```
private ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, you already have yours)
    ArrayList<String> menu_Items = new ArrayList<String>();
    menu_Items.add("Fill Treatment Form");
    menu_Items.add("View Medical History");
    menu_Items.add("View Medication");
    menu_Items.add("View Diet");
    menu_Items.add("View First Aid");
    menu_Items.add("Look Up Map");
    menu_Items.add("Account Settings");
    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu_Items);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FillTreatmentActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg1, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicalHistoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg2, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicationActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg3, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DietActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg4, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstAidActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg5, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg6, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }); 
}
```

When I click any of the listview item Accounte Settings Activity opens.
I am a newbie so please don't judge my coding :)

Comment: You're overriding the last listener every time you call `setOnItemClickListener()`. You should use one listener that can handle the difference between items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a switch statement to your click listener

```
private ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, you already have yours)
    ArrayList<String> menu_Items = new ArrayList<String>();
    menu_Items.add("Fill Treatment Form");
    menu_Items.add("View Medical History");
    menu_Items.add("View Medication");
    menu_Items.add("View Diet");
    menu_Items.add("View First Aid");
    menu_Items.add("Look Up Map");
    menu_Items.add("Account Settings");
    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu_Items);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch(position){
          case 0:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FillTreatmentActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 1:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicalHistoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 2:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicationActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 3:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DietActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 4:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstAidActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 5:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 6:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        break;

        }


        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A listview can only have one `OnItemClickListener`, so all but the last are thrown away. That's the reason why `SettingsActivity` is openend no matter which item you tap.

To solve it, use one listener and let this one handle the different options.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg1, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch(position) {
           case 0:
               // start activity 1
               break;
           case 1:
               // start activity 2
               break;
           case 2:
               // start activity 3
               break;
           // more case statements

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wh ydon't you add `android:onClick="myClickMethod"` in the layout for the `listview` and then create a method with the same name? Inthere, you can see whick view exactly has been pressed. Also the listView has only one `onClickListener` ;-)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it; I was doing it wrong.
Thanks for the help guys. 
Peace /

```
private ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, you already have yours)
    ArrayList<String> menu_Items = new ArrayList<String>();
    menu_Items.add("Fill Treatment Form");
    menu_Items.add("View Medical History");
    menu_Items.add("View Medication");
    menu_Items.add("View Diet");
    menu_Items.add("View First Aid");
    menu_Items.add("Look Up Map");
    menu_Items.add("Account Settings");
    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu_Items);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch(position){
          case 0:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FillTreatmentActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        break;
          case 1:
        Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicalHistoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(j);
        break;
          case 2:
        Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MedicationActivity.class);
            startActivity(k);
        break;
          case 3:
        Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DietActivity.class);
                startActivity(l);
        break;
          case 4:
        Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstAidActivity.class);
                startActivity(m);
        break;
          case 5:
        Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(n);
        break;
          case 6:
        Intent o = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(o);
        break;

        }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to create on Listener which will process all list. Something like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg6, View view, int position, long id) {
swith(position){
        case 1:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FillTreatmentActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 2:
        ...
        }
        }
    });
```

Or you can extends class ArrayAdaptyer and realize for each element single listener